# Azure Website running WordPress Multi-Site Slow Initial Response

Tags: wordpress, azure-web-app-service, multisite

I am running a WordPress Multisite in an Azure Website with 3 websites and the performance of all of them are okay except for the initial load request.  It is almost like it takes 3-4 seconds for the site to even start loading.  I have enabled the always on option in the azure website configuration and that didnt seem to help anything.

Any ideas?  This is happening to two different Websites on different Azure accounts that I have.  The sites are running different plugins and themes so I don't think it is that.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Having the exact same problem - my question about it is here http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/176041/how-can-i-diagnose-a-slow-wordpress-admin/

Comment: Thanks!  I will look into downgrading on of my wordpress multi sites and see if it helps. I will post an update to your thread when I am done testing!

Comment: It worked wonderfully for me - not ideal, but a solution nonetheless

Comment: Is the URL of the sites public?  Post them up for a pass with some profiling tools....